# How to close a popup in lightning by hitting Escape button on keypad

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a lightning component where a popup opens up on certain instruction. now i want to close this popup when even Esc button on keypad is hit.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I am concerned, the easiest way would be to use the [lightning:overlayLibrary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:overlayLibrary/documentation) component in order to achieve what you are looking for. This component supports Out of the box closing when hitting the ESC key or pressing the cancel button.

> Pressing the Escape key or clicking the close button closes the modal.